# Why TeXForm[] do not display to notebook if followed by OutputForm[] in same cell?

Tags: notebooks, latex, cells

Can someone please explain to me the logic of this:

In one cell, when writing

```
eq = D[y[x], x] + a*y[x] - b*Sin[c*x];
sol = DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x];
TeXForm[sol]
OutputForm[TeXForm[sol]]
```

I see only the result of `OutputForm`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But in separate cells, then I see both outputs

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I was trying to find how to remove the "\" at the end of the `OutputForm` compared to `TeXForm` output, and that is why I am doing the above, to compare the outputs.

This happens on both V9 and 10.  Should not both output show up, even if in the same cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like OutputForm always is the first output one gets and all previous Out[..] are removed if they are equal. Here equal means that Out[1]==Out[2], and not necessarily that Out[1]/TeXForm==Out[2]/OutputForm.

You can change the order to:

```
eq = D[y[x], x] + a*y[x] - b*Sin[c*x];
sol = DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x];
OutputForm[TeXForm[sol]]
TeXForm[sol]
```

> \left{\left{y(x)\to \frac{b (a \sin (c x)-c \cos (c x))}{a^2+c^2}+c_1 e^{-a x}\right}\right}
>
> \left{\left{y(x)\to \frac{b (a \sin (c x)-c \cos (c x))}{a^2+c^2}+c_1 e^{-a x}\right}\right}

Your "\" at the end of the `OutputForm` is just a linebreak. It will be removed, if you make Mma window wider.